# Firebase realtime - get array of all the children keys

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");



exports.impersonateMakeUpperCase = functions.database
.ref('Searching for match/level')
.onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
    
    /// get all the children keys under 'level'

 });
```

I'm trying to make a **function**, returning an **array** of all the **children keys** under **"Searching for match/level"** every time a time child is added to there, any solution?

Comment: What is the problem you're having with the code you shared?

Comment: the code I shared is just a callback when a new child is created, I'm trying to list all the existed children

Comment: What have you already tried? For me the code you share is more a snippet rather than an attempt of accomplish what you need.